# Protractor Locator for elements of same class

Tags: html, css, typescript, protractor

I'm new to Protractor and E2E testing and want to determine whether my approach to CSS locators is correct for identical elements of the same class.

I have an [HTML Fiddle here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1WTVA8EK3U8) that depicts a webpage with two div elements, each containing two buttons: the buttons are all of the same class. HTML follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    <button class="btn1" tooltip="Color">
              <span class="color-indicator" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
    </button>
    <button class="btn1" tooltip="Background Color">
              <span class="color-indicator" style="background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);">
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn1" tooltip="Color">
              <span class="color-indicator" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
    </button>
    <button class="btn1" tooltip="Background Color">
              <span class="color-indicator" style="background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);">
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to click each button element in each `div`. The buttons can be accessed by **element(by.css())** Locator using their CSS selectors (e.g. **"body > div:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1)"**) but is there a better way to access these items?

My website has many instances like this, and I'd like to know if there is a better way to access elements like this, other than hardcoding their **nth-child** numbers in my **it()** scripts. The elements on the webpages might be reordered in the future, and so using numbering might result in broken cases down the road.

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the exact amount of buttons with the same class, you can locate them with css selector; in this case, there are 4, so it'd look like this::

```
element.all(by.css('.btn1')).get(0);
element.all(by.css('.btn1')).get(1);
element.all(by.css('.btn1')).get(2);
element.all(by.css('.btn1')).get(3);
```

Let me know if it helped!

Comment: That seems cleaner. Thank you!